# Unit Testing Moq not passing through method when virtual

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, moq

Hi say I have some code like:

```
public class Class1
    {
        public  int MyMethod()
        {
            return MyOtherMethod();
        }

        public virtual int MyOtherMethod()
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
```

Ok, this doesn't do much of relevance but this is just for a simple example.

I then create a new test:

```
[TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            var t = new Mock<Class1>();

            var w = t.Object.MyMethod();
        }
```

Could someone please tell me why the code runs through the called method MyOtherMethod when it's not designated as virtual but when you make it virtual the test code refuses to go through that method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should setup the virtual method before you calling MyMethod:

```
t.Setup(c => c.MyOtherMethod()).Return(1);
```